# liveUSB/ISO, terminal in GUI: user is not allowed to execute as root; works before startx

Tags: linux, terminal, sudo, live-usb

I've created new `test` user (`sudo adduser test`), added to `sudo` via `sudo usermod test -G sudo`.

Then I switch to other terminal (Alt-Ctrl-F2), login as `test`, `sudo echo a`: "a" - ok, but `startx`, start gnome terminal and `sudo echo a` output "user is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/echo a' as root". Any ideas why? TIA

This "feature" appears to work only with liveISO boot, I wonder how it works, live boot is still Linux, the only difference I know with regular one is in using overlayfs for root `/` to put modifiable fs on top of non-modifiable file with all `/` from iso.

`/etc/sudoers` just list `%sudo ALL ALL`, `sudo -l` does not show anything for `test`. (those possible causes of error I've found vie web search and checked out).

System: Linux Mint 21, liveiso boot.

Answer (score 2):

This might sound silly but have you tried logging in again, logout > login.
For a new group membership to be effective this is required under linux.

Comment: Full story: you get your user and groups at login (and in part of login procedure). They are not checked dynamically. You can also ssh locally, if you cannot logout. (or with su, etc, but possibly you do not have access to it now)

Comment: Thanks, I have not said it explicitly. I typed `startx` right after confirming `sudo` works. so yes, it all was after re-login (or on first login of new account). I've noted it is for liveISO boot and edited the question. Yet another thing I notice about liveISO/USB boot. I'm curious how it is done to work like that.